# RETURN jump missing in iptables userchain - what happens?

Tags: iptables

I am quite unable to find out what the consequences of a missing RETURN-rule at the end of user-defined iptables chains are. Obviously "iptables [missing] return [jump]" are really, really bad keywords to look for.

The manpage and any blog or howto I could dig up just tell me what `-j RETURN` does (which is quite obvious) but not what happens if it is missing. Also, I cannot seem to set up sane experimental rules to try it out...

```
iptables -N userchainA
iptables -A INPUT -j userchainA
iptables -N userchainB
iptables -A INPUT -j userchainB
iptables -A INPUT -j ACCEPT

iptables -A userchainA ... # anything here, that DOES NOT MATCH
#### no explicit return from userchainA!

iptables -A userchainB ... # anything here, that DOES NOT MATCH
iptables -A userchainB -j RETURN
```

Given these rules, anything works just fine. Packets travel through all the chains and finally hit the `ACCEPT from INPUT` as if the (missing) `-j RETURN` from `userchainA` would be done implicitly. Is this the case?

Why is this working? I would have expected some kind of error or at least a log message about execution falling of a chain.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[When iptables reaches the end of a user-defined chain, flow returns to the next rule in the calling chain.](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/packet-filtering-HOWTO-7.html#ss7.4) The RETURN is therefore implicit; it does not need to be explicitly given.

Comment: Argh! I knew this would be a short one. Thanks for pointing me to this.

Comment: Every rule has a default target -- something has to happen if a packet doesn't match any rule in the chain.

Comment: Sorry, David, but only built-in chains can have policies set; user-defined tables, such as the one in this question, can not.  Check the man page on `iptables -P`.